# Modify Assembly-CSharp.dll before send to IL2CPP in Unity3d

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I want to insert some code stub to Assembly-CSharp.dll by using Mono.Cecil before send to il2cpp when build iOS player with batchmode.

Currently, the only way I know is to wrap Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\UnusedByteCodeStripper2\UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe to execute my patcher before real stripper.

Is there any other better way like [DidReloadScripts] to do this?

For Android, I can patch dlls after BuildPlayer. But for iOS with il2cpp, there is no dll generated before BuildPlayer.

Comment: here's the solution i mentioned,
using [HotPatchEnabler](https://github.com/xiaobin83/Unity3D.HotPatchEnabler)
 with [UnusedBytecodeStripper2.Chain](https://github.com/xiaobin83/Unity3D.UnusedBytecodeStripper2.Chain)
UnusedBytecodeStripper2.Chain find all class with IProcessDLL and execute them before executing original UnusedBytecodeStripper2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i wrote my own UnusedBytecodeStripper2 to replace the original one, and make the original one as part of process chain.

Check [this](https://github.com/xiaobin83/Unity3D.UnusedBytecodeStripper2.Chain)